# how to horizontally Scrolling to specfic point in a slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm creating a piano key style slider where once an element is clicked its grows in width. This creates a problem where if i click an item that is close to the edges of the screen or is already being cut of by the edge, the content is out of view and the user needs to scroll left or right to see the content.

My question is this:  Is there a way to get an element in a slider, once, clicked, to move to  a specific point past the left edge of the screen? For example have it position itself (with smooth transitions) 50px to the right of the far left edge of the screen?

this is what I've tried

```js
const buttonRight = document.getElementById("right-arrow");
const buttonLeft = document.getElementById("left-arrow");
const slider = document.getElementById("card-wrapper");
const sliderCards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
buttonLeft.addEventListener("click", () => {
  slider.scrollLeft -= 400;
});
buttonRight.addEventListener("click", () => {
  slider.scrollLeft += 400;
});
sliderCards.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (item.classList.contains('active')) {
      item.classList.remove('active')
    } else {
      document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.remove('active');
      });
      item.classList.add('active');
      item.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "center",
        inline: "center"
      });
    };
  });
});
```

```css
#slider-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}

.slider-team-img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slider-hidden-text {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  font-family: Jost, Sans-Serif;
  line-height: 31px;
}

.card.active .slider-hidden-text {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.card.active .brand-name {
  font-size: 30px !important;
  line-height: 34px !important;
  z-index: 2 !important;
}

.slider-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
  height: 560px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.slider-content .card-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 560px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end !important;
  overflow-x: auto !important;
  scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
}

@media all and (max-width:2187px) {
  .slider-content .card-wrapper {
    justify-content: flex-start !important;
  }
}

.slider-content .card {
  margin-left: 14px;
  margin-right: 14px;
  min-width: 232px;
  height: 480px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: center !important;
}

.slider-content .card:not(.active):hover {
  height: 520px;
  min-width: 271px;
  margin-left: 24px;
  margin-right: 24px;
  transform: scaleX(1.1731) scaleY(1.0831);
  transform-origin: bottom !important;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.slider-content .card.active {
  flex-grow: 1 !important;
  min-width: 753px;
}

.slider-content .card.active:hover {
  margin-left: 74px;
  margin-right: 74px;
  transform: scaleX(1.1731) scaleY(1.0831);
  transform-origin: bottom !important;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.slider-content .card-content {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 40px 20px 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal medium 14px/20px Jost;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.slider-content .card.active .card-content {
  align-items: flex-start !important;
}

.slider-content .card-content img {
  max-height: 60px;
}

.slider-content .slide-1 {
  background: red !important;
  background-position: center !important;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slider-content .slide-2 {
  background: blue !important;
  background-position: center !important;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slider-content .slide-3 {
  background: green !important;
  background-position: center !important;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slider-controls-wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px !important;
}

.controls img {
  cursor: pointer !important;
  width: 56px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-content">
    <div class="card-wrapper" id="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card slide-1 ">
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="slider-hidden-text">
            content goes here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card slide-2 ">
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="slider-hidden-text">
            content goes here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card slide-3 ">
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="slider-hidden-text">
            content goes here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="slider-controls-wrapper">
    <div class="controls">
      <img id="left-arrow" src="">
      <img id="right-arrow" src="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"once an element is clicked its grows in width"_ - don't see where that is supposed to happen, can only assume that happens via the `active` class the elements get assigned? Please provide a proper [mre], when asking this kind of question.